# Show that :$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx={(2n)!!\over (2n+1)!!}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I show that

> Let $n\ge0$. Then,
>   $$I:=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx={(2n)!!\over (2n+1)!!}$$
>   Here, $m!!$ denotes the product of all positive integers $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$ that have the same parity as $m$.

My try:
Using Binomial theorem

$$(1-x^2)=1-nx^2+{n(n+1)\over2!}x^4-{n(n+1)(n+2)\over 3!}x^6+\cdots$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-nx^2+{n(n+1)\over2!}x^4-{n(n+1)(n+2)\over 3!}x^6+\cdots\right)dx$$

$$I=x-n{x^3\over 3}+{n(n+1)\over 2!}{x^5\over 5}-{n(n+1)(n+2)\over 3!}{x^7\over 7}+\cdots|_{0}^{1}$$

$$I=1-{n\over 1\cdot 3}+{n(n+1)\over 2!\cdot 5}-{n(n+1)(n+2)\over 3!\cdot  7}+\cdots$$

I need help can't see how it will simplify to ${(2n)!!\over (2n+1)!!}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074881/how-to-integrate-this-function-int1-x2ndx

Comment: What a coincidence both asked the same question today.

Comment: @Felix, can you explain why you don't think it's a dupe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint**. *Integrating by parts* gives
$$
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx&=\left[x(1-x^2)^n\right]_{0}^{1}+2n\int_{0}^{1}x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}dx
\\\\&=0+2n\int_{0}^{1}\left[(1-(1-x^2))(1-x^2)^{n-1}\right]dx
\\\\&=2nI_{n-1}-2nI_{n}
\end{align}
$$ then, with $I_0=1,\,I_1=\frac23,$
$$
I_{n}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\cdot I_{n-1}, \quad n\ge1.
$$
I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Perfect!  $\color{white}{\text{Amazingly perfect!}}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=x^{2}$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^{2})^{n} dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-z)^{n} z^{-1/2} dz \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{B}(1/2,n+1) \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(n+1)}{2\Gamma(n+3/2)} \\
\tag{1}
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}n!}{(2n+1)\Gamma(n+1/2)} \\
\tag{2}
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}n!}{(2n+1)} \frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n-1)!!} \\
&= \frac{n!2^{n}}{(2n+1)} \frac{n!2^{n}}{(2n)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n)!!n!2^{n}}{(2n+1)!} \\
&= \frac{(2n)!!n!2^{n}}{(2n+1)!!n!2^{n}} \\
&= \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}
\end{align}

1. $\Gamma(n+3/2) = \Gamma((n+1/2)+1) = (n+1/2)\Gamma(n+1/2)$
2. $$\Gamma(n+1/2) = \frac{(2n-1)!!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{n}}$$
3. All double factorial identities used can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html).