# Computing $\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^n\ dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, beta-function

I'd like to calculate $\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^n\ dx$, but I have no idea how. After searching through this website, I found out that we can transform the integral into Beta function, by using substitution. However, I'm having trouble finding the right substitution. I tried using $x = 1 - 2t$. Then the integral becomes
$$-\frac{4^n}{2}\int_{3}^{-1}t^n(1-t)^n\ dt.$$
What's inside the integral is similar to Beta function. But the boundaries are not. It should have been
$$\int_0^1t^n(1-t)^n\ dt.$$
Any idea what substitution should I choose?

Comment: If $n\in\Bbb N$ you can use binomial expansion.

Comment: Did you try $x =\sin \theta$ (or $\cos \theta$)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Integrate this function $\int(1-x^2)^ndx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074881/how-to-integrate-this-function-int1-x2ndx)

Comment: Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074931/show-that-int-011-x2ndx-2n-over-2n1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution leads to the correct bounds. It seems like you used $x = 1 - 2t$ and substituted $t = -1, 1$ when it should have been the other way around: Use $t = \frac{1}{2}(1-x)$ and substitute $x = -1, 1$.